# How to run multiple commands in _popen

Tags: c++, pipe, chess

I'm making a software that runs stockfish. So far I have:

```
std::string exec(std::string cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }

    return result;
}
int main(){
    std::cout << exec("stockfish position startpos moves e2e4") << std::cout;
}
```

this works perfectly. But the way stockfish works is if I want to evaluate this position in chess I first have to also run the command "go depth 10". So in theory that would look like:

```
int main(){
    std::cout << exec("stockfish position startpos moves e2e4 & go depth 10") << std::cout;
}

output: 
Stockfish 091021 by the Stockfish developers (see AUTHORS file)
info string NNUE evaluation using nn-13406b1dcbe0.nnue enabled
info depth 1 seldepth 1 multipv 1 score cp 38 nodes 20 nps 20000 tbhits 0 time 1 pv d2d4
info depth 2 seldepth 2 multipv 1 score cp 82 nodes 50 nps 25000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e2e4 a7a6
info depth 3 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 65 nodes 122 nps 61000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv g1f3 h7h6 d2d4
info depth 4 seldepth 4 multipv 1 score cp 41 nodes 456 nps 152000 tbhits 0 time 3 pv g1f3 d7d5 d2d4 c7c6
info depth 5 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 22 nodes 1409 nps 201285 tbhits 0 time 7 pv c2c4 e7e5 d2d4 e5d4 d1d4
info depth 6 seldepth 6 multipv 1 score cp 25 nodes 1973 nps 219222 tbhits 0 time 9 pv g1f3 c7c5 c2c4 g8f6 d2d4 c5d4 f3d4
info depth 7 seldepth 7 multipv 1 score cp 39 nodes 2804 nps 215692 tbhits 0 time 13 pv g1f3 d7d5 e2e3 e7e6 c2c4 d5c4 f1c4
info depth 8 seldepth 10 multipv 1 score cp 49 nodes 8782 nps 214195 tbhits 0 time 41 pv e2e4 c7c5 b1c3 d7d6 g1e2 e7e5 c3d5
info depth 9 seldepth 12 multipv 1 score cp 36 nodes 17265 nps 218544 tbhits 0 time 79 pv e2e4 c7c6 d2d4 d7d5 b1d2 d5e4 d2e4 g8f6 e4f6 e7f6
info depth 10 seldepth 13 multipv 1 score cp 47 nodes 21380 nps 222708 tbhits 0 time 96 pv e2e4 c7c5 b1c3 d7d6 g1e2 e7e5 e2g3 c8e6 c3d5
bestmove e2e4 ponder c7c5
```

the 'bestmove' stockfish gives me is nothing like I put into it. **It ignores my 'startpos'.**

My question: Is there a way to run multiple commands into a pipe that doesn't disrupt the previous command written?

Comment: Would you normally have to escape the ampersand when running that command from the command line?  Or does typing that exact command on the command line  work?

Comment: The reason I ask is because on windows cmd uses & to join commands but you can escape it with a ^  So try `stockfish position startpos moves e2e4 ^& go depth 10`